# WPF / C#, Adding rows to GridView after adding columns

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I can't for the life of me figure out how to add rows to a ListView.  I don't understand why this doesn't work when it works just fine for ListBox (without the rows).. i feel like i'm missing something really simple here, can someone help me out?

EDIT: didn't paste all the code sorry

```
<ListView Margin="10" Name="lvUsers">
        <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" Width="150" />
                </GridView>
        </ListView.View>


<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="45"> <!--Stacks Items Horizontally-->
                            <ComboBox Width="100" Height="30">
                                <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">DirecTV</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Hyundai</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>None</ComboBoxItem>
                            </ComboBox>
                            <TextBox Width="445" Height="30" Text="Follow RedZone on Twitter" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="True" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"></ScaleTransform>
                                </CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                            </CheckBox>
                        <Button Content="Delete"  Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"/>
                    </StackPanel>
</ListView>
```

Comment: You don't "add rows" to a GridView. You `BIND` the ItemsSource to some relevant collection of data items. and let WPF handle the UI elements.

Comment: Where is the Listview here?

Comment: ah I didn't know that HighCore.  I guess that's all i needed to know.  thought i could add a row by using ListViewItem or something

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment section, Bind your `ListView` (although by your code looks like you aiming for a `DataGrid`) to some collection and it will create an "row" for every element in the collection.

You can define columns and bind them to properties of your elements

```
    <DataGrid Margin="10" Name="lvUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Mail}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>    
    </DataGrid>
```

Also, you need to set the `DataContext` of the window to the class containing your collection (Known as ViewModel)

```
<Window.DataContext>
   <local:MyViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

If your not familar with MVVM or Bindings, here are some links to get you started

MVVM:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36545/WPF-MVVM-Model-View-View-Model-Simplified

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial

Bindings:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140621/WPF-Tutorial-Concept-Binding

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Good luck